# Natural way to talk about food served in a restaurant

Tags: expressions

I'm looking for some good ways to express whether food or other consumables are served at a restaurant. Here is some ideas I have:

```
この辺のレストランではラーメンを出してない  (or  "〜が出てない"?)
この辺のレストランではラーメンを扱ってない
この辺のレストランではラーメンを取り扱ってない
この辺のレストランではラーメンを売ってない
```

Which of these are natural or best for everyday conversation? If there are any other common ones I've missed please let me know.

Comment: 少し細かいですが、そもそも「レストラン」は、ラーメンを出すようなお店を呼称するのにはあまり使われないという気もします。「レストラン」と聞くとまずは西洋風の飲食店を思い浮かべます。なので「この辺りの」というのがやや引っかかり気味です。

Answer (score 4):

Among the four options you listed, ラーメンを出していない／出さない sounds the most natural to me. You can also say 「**この辺の店はラーメンをやって(い)ない**」 , which would sound equally natural and even more casual.

ラーメンを扱う and ラーメンを取り扱う sounds too formal and stiff for everyday conversations. ～を売る店 is okay for ordinary shops, but not for restaurants. I think ハンバーグを売る店／寿司を売る店／etc will almost never be heard from native speakers.

Answer (score 1):

I like naruto's reply, but I'd be curious of your intent since your format seems a bit odd.

In addition you may want to consider the below as a reference. It doesn't quite fit your mold but it feels more natural.

この辺でラーメンを食べられるお店（レストラン）はありますか。

or

この辺でラーメンを食べられるお店（レストラン）はありません。